# What are the KPIs for a successful UI/UX design?

Tags: interface-design

How do you measure that your design improvements did in fact improve session duration/views?

Comment: This is quite a broad question, but admittedly interesting and useful

Comment: I would think there is chance that one would get a better/ faster answer on [ux.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/). Any thoughts?

Comment: I agree it an interesting question but you're more likely to get better answers on [ux.se] (that's not to say it's off-topic here though).